# There's a way to stop the execution point at the error?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

i was wondering if there's any way to stop the execution point at the error in Delphi

like

```
StrToInt('1'); < ok
StrToInt('A'); < execution point stops here to show me where's the error
StrToInt('2');
```

Comment: Debugger options, break on exception. It will break inside `StrToInt` of course. Use the call stack to see how it got there.

Comment: there's no break on exception in debugger options menu

Comment: Yes there is. [Notify on Language Exceptions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Language_Exceptions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting is here: *Options | Debugger Options | Embarcadero Debuggers | Language Exceptions* and the setting is named *Notify on language exceptions*. You need it to be checked.

The IDE will break at the point where the exception is raised. In your code that is inside the call to `StrToInt`. Use the call stack to work out where the call originated.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i want!

Comment: Additionally, "Integrated Debugging" needs to be on, and the particular exception class (in this case, `EConvertError`) should not be in the list of exceptions to ignore.